# Part of background cut off on mobile

Tags: html, css, background

I have a weird background bug on my site, http://www.andytechguy.com/ . You can see that when you go on a mobile browser and search the site, a part of the gradients at the top get chopped off. I have no idea what is going on with that, I didn't add anything to make that happen and it doesn't look good. Please help?

Comment: have you tried setting `width:100%` to `#nav` and `#top_part`?  That may solve the issue but I'm not sure

Comment: I think it's `twelfth`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `#main_part` has a fixed width of 1050px. But the rest of the site is assuming the width is about 980px. (980px in my mobile)

Just add a css rule like this:

```
html {
   width: 1050px;
}
```

And you'll notice that the top bar is not longer chopped off.

---

However, that annoying horizontal scroll may still be there (but this time without empty space)

Nothing of this is a replacement to actually create a responsive website. That in the end is the *real* solution. May I suggest that you convert your website to [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/)?

Comment: Nice work. the only problem is that when I view it on my computer, it looks weird. I might just edit it so it will detect a mobile browser and then make it that amount of pixels

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell your `h2` text is larger on mobile vs desktop.  This probably has to do with font rendering and your reltive size of `1.5em`.

Your background gradient is 70px tall.  On mobile it is repeating itself since the header's height is greater than 70px.

I would modify your CSS like so:

*CSS*

```css
#section h2 {

     /* remove this */
     padding: 20px;

     /* add these two */
     height: 70px;
     line-height: 70px; /* this will vertically align the text */

}
```

Comment: I tried changing that. It looks good but I still get the cut off... I do give you thanks for trying though!

Comment: Please make the changes live so I can verify this.

Comment: Sure, I updated the CSS a few minutes ago, check for yourself

Comment: Looks goods on my end. Make sure your browser isn't using a caching your CSS.

Comment: Are you talking about the area in the upper-right where it just doesn't fit the full width?

Comment: @eshellborn Yeah, that's exactly what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Move your div inside "container" class and create your own custom class like below:

```
.custom-container{
    min-width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

overall, write this

```
<div class="container custom-container">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```